# Printing with css style

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, printing

I have a css stylesheet linked to my webpage. When I view the webpage it look how it is supposed to look, but when I print the document I don't see the style anymore. I've added the css a second time with the attribute: `media='print'` but it won't work. Does anybody know how to use the `window.print()` function and keeping the style to the printing document?

ASPX:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="cpHead" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="Styles/Site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="Styles/Site.css" />
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" ClientIDMode="AutoID">
    <asp:Image ID="imgHeader" Width="100%" runat="server" />
    <asp:GridView ID="gvPrintData" Width="100%" runat="server" HeaderStyle-CssClass="printGridHeader" RowStyle-CssClass="printGridRow" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="printGridAltRow" />
</asp:Content>
```

.CS:

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.print(); window.onfocus = function() { window.close(); }</script>");
```

Pageview (how it should look):
[image: Page]

Printedview (how it looks on the printed document):
[image: Doc]

Comment: In general I have found printing HTML to be inconsistent across browsers and troublesome in general, not to mention it rarely looks good.  Any chance you can output a .pdf file for print?

Comment: Have you cleared your cache? Browsers can sometimes not get the newest versions of files if it is in their caches.

Comment: @vari, the cache has no play in this.  The browser is turning off background styles after the content is sent to it.  This is not a programming/api issue, its a browser setting issue that has plagued web developers for years.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your stylesheet is actually working - look at the heading font.  What I suspect is happening is the browser is not printing background colours.

Go to the Page Setup / Print setup in your browser and check that background images and colours is turned on.

**Firefox**

[image: Firefox]

**IE9**

[image: IE9]

Comment: And unfortunately, theres not a great way to circumvent this for all clients.  its a browser setting that we cannot change.  Your users must do it themselves.

Comment: @Kirean Probably good for the planet - think of all that saved toner :)

Comment: Thank you 4 your replay! I refreshed a couple of times and deleted the cache but that doesn't solve the problem. I have alreay a PDF export function but I need this to work in a separate way. And the windows from your screenshot isn't a window that I can acces from my print dialog and theres no option to print background in my print dialog or on any subdialogs. Does anybody know something else to try?

Comment: @psynnott yep.  I generally advise people to not print out websites anymore (as they weren't made for current web 2.0 application), but Ive had my fair share of clients that have said "but why cant my user print my site?!?"  Sad story, but its 2012, you dont need the paper copy!

Comment: @WesleyLalieu its a *browser* setting.  This is not accessible from the print dialog, but rather browser tools/settings.  As far as I know, there is no override in the API to force it, each user must turn it on.

Comment: @WesleyLalieu  what browser are you using?  These settinsg are accessible by anyone, they are independant of the printer driver - so you should see them.  It's under File, PAGE setup, not print setup.

Comment: I know what you mean, but in this case it's about the printing. The user can make a own report with my system, and then they need to print that report. And please no chrystal reports or anything like that, it's like going to hell :P. But it should be possible to print a styled webpage I think. Anyone else?

Comment: I use IE9. but I need it to work with all the users. Is that possible?

Comment: @WesleyLalieu You can't override this setting.  You're requesting the browser print the page.  The browser decides how it will print it.  Unfortunately if the user has this setting unticked, you wont get background colours :(

Comment: Okay thank you, so the only way to get this right would be to use images instead of background colors I guess. Thank you everyone!

Comment: @WesleyLalieu sorry, browsers turn off background images too.  There is absolutely no way to force the browser to print a background.  Its there to save ink/toner.

Comment: I know but a normal image and not a background image with the text over the image would look like a background but isn't one. That's possible I think.

Comment: @WesleyLalieu Good luck - it should work but I would hate to maintain that code